# Modify Symfony2 routing to prepend all requests with application name

Tags: php, apache, symfony, mod-rewrite

I want to host two instances of the same Symfony2 application on one Apache server. Each application should be addressed like so:

http://myserver/app1/
http://myserver/app2/

To do so I have set up two port based virtual hosts in Apache plus the third one on port 80 that redirects folder requests to proper vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app1/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:9999/%1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app2/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8888/%1 [L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:9999>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app1/web    
    <Directory /var/www/app1/web>   
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app2/web        
    <Directory /var/www/app2/web>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That works perfectly as http://myserver/app1/ is redirected to http://myserver:9999 and http://myserver/app2/ is redirected to http://myserver:8888 (the URL in browser changes). I want the URL in web browser to stay as http://myserver/app1 or http://myserver/app2. 
I can do this by adding switch 'P' to RewriteRule, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:9999/%1 [L,P]
```

This however creates problem, because now Symfony sees all requests to be coming from port 80 and redirects them back to that port not to the proper virtual host. I think one way to fix this issue would be to force Symfony2 to prepend all requests with the proper application name.
I tried to do so by modifying generateUrl method in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php to always add application name in front of generated URL and it worked but only for page requests (assets were missing for example).

So my question is if there is a way to full Symfony into thinking that all requests should go back to proper 'app' URL?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you don't try to do this via Apache configuration. You can configure each Symfony application to live in a subfolder, see:
http://www.yegods.it/2015/01/30/install-symfony-app-in-a-subfolder-of-an-existing-site/

You only need to edit *app.php*, *app_dev.php* and *composer.json* (for assets).